# CodedUI assert a nonexistent element

Tags: visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

my problem is that I want to check that an element is not displayed. In other words I want to check that an element was deleted.

So I am developing an automatic test that has a option to disable comments. I want to check that the textfield for the comments is nonexistent. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish between the element (a text field or something) being not displayed and it being empty.

If the field is displayed but is empty then a simple assertion that the value is the empty string will work.

If the field is not displayed at all then an attempt on an assertion will fail with a control not found exception. The relevant code can be enclosed within a try-catch block that expects to catch the exception

```
try {
    ... access the control...;
    Assert.Fail("The control was found but it should not be present.");
}
catch (UITestControlNotFoundException ) {
    // Success path.
}
```

Make sure that the `... access the control...;` checks for the correct level in thy control hierarchy. You may also want to enclose it with code to fail quickly when the control is not present, by default Coded UI may wait in case the application is slow to draw the control.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
Bool isExists = (Boolean)BrowserWindow.ExecuteScript("return $('#yourcontrolId').length > 0;");

if(isExists) 
  Assert.Fail("Control is not deleted");

// Success Code
```